# FIle is not being copied in WORKDIR from Image recipe in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I am trying to install a simple file to /etc directory of target rootfs. I am building `core-image-sato`. "raxy_test" file(in below recipe) is not even being copied in WORKDIR also.

> Am I doing anything wrong?

I am able to do same with normal recipe but not with image recipe.

> What is the difference between normal and image recipe?

```
DESCRIPTION = "Image with Sato, a mobile environment and visual style for \                                                                                                                    
mobile devices. The image supports X11 with a Sato theme, Pimlico \
applications, and contains terminal, editor, and file manager."

IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management x11-base x11-sato ssh-server-dropbear hwcodecs"

LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image

TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-intltool nativesdk-glib-2.0"
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_remove_task-populate-sdk-ext = " nativesdk-intltool nativesdk-glib-2.0"

LICENSE="CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM="" 

SRC_URI = "\
          file://raxy_test \
          "   
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0755 raxy_test ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

I expect "raxy_test" file to be present in WORKDIR as well as in /etc directory of target.

Any help will really be appreciated, Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things:

- You use a image recipe (`core-image-sato`) to add a file in your image. You should use a separate recipe for this modification;
- The `install` is not correct ([WORKDIR](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-WORKDIR) is not used);
- You do not populate the packages ([FILES_${PN}](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILES) not present).

---

For the separate recipe, create a file (for example `myrecipe.bb` or whatever you want) in a recipes-* sub directory (you need to place it at the same folder level than other recipes !). I did not test it but I think this can be a base:

```
DESCRIPTION = "My recipe"
LICENSE="CLOSED"

PR = "r0"
PV = "0.1"

SRC_URI = " file://raxy_test "

 # Create package specific skeleton
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/raxy_test ${D}${sysconfdir}/raxy_test
}

# Populate packages
FILES_${PN} = "${sysconfdir}"
```

You can notice that some things have changed:

The `install` must include the ${WORKDIR} path:

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/raxy_test ${D}${sysconfdir}
```

And we need to populate the package:

```
FILES_${PN} = "${sysconfdir}"
```

This will add the files in `${sysconfdir}` into the package `${PN}` (which is by default the recipe name).

Comment: By default FILES_${PN} contains ${sysconfdir} so you don't need to add it unless you install something in an unusual folder. You also probably want to use `+=` operator instead of `=`.

Comment: Also, if recipe is only configuration with no binaries, you can add `inherit allarch`.